# Json.Net is NULLing Nullable<Bool> on Deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I have set up a WebAPI controller that returns a dataset that has a nullable boolean (can_personalize) on the SQL DB.

When I download the .json file directly, the boolean property contains data (true/false). When I use the Newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), the can_personalize property values for every object is NULL.

I have tried suggestions in several other question responses similar but none have triage the problem.

JSON example:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "TagTypeID": 1,
      "tagIndex": 0,
      "TagCategoryId": 1,
      "validtagtypeid": 0,
      "PrimaryTagTypeValue": "MC",
      "PrimaryDescription": "Motorcycle - Standard",
      "TagCategory": "StandardPlate",
      "SecondaryTagTypeValue": "02",
      "SecondaryDescription": "Personalized",
      "TagEndDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00",
      "PrimaryEndDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00",
      "SecondaryEndDate": "12/31/9999",
      "ValidRegex": "^[A-Z\\d -]{1,7}$",
      "primarytagtypeid": 78,
      "secondarytagtypeid": 2,
      "can_personalize": true,
      "ImageName": "redacted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Class generated by ADO.NET Model:

```
public partial class ttGetTagListWithCategory_Result
{
    public long TagTypeID { get; set; }
    public int tagIndex { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TagCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int validtagtypeid { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryTagTypeValue { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryDescription { get; set; }
    public string TagCategory { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryTagTypeValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TagEndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PrimaryEndDate { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryEndDate { get; set; }
    public string ValidRegex { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> primarytagtypeid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> secondarytagtypeid { get; set; }
    public bool can_personalize { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

JsonConvert call:

```
List<ttGetTagTypeListWithCategory_Result> tagTypeWithCategory =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ttGetTagTypeListWithCategory_Result>>
            (client.DownloadString(WebApiUtility.GetTagTypeListWithCategoryUri()));
```

Comment: Can you show the string you're trying to deserialize, the class you're deserializing into, and the expected and actual output?

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: I also notice that the can_personalize is not nullable on the class... hmmm

Comment: Could you add your call to DeserializeObject?

Comment: Added the JsonConvert call

Comment: If that's your actual json as passed to `DeserializeObject`, then the problem is that your collection is nested. You aren't passing it the part that represents your collection, you are passing it a parent object that contains the collection.

Comment: Why you mix lover case and upper case property names? it could be a problem.

Comment: Matt, that is one entry of 160.

Comment: MajoB, I don't know why...I'm trying to build a WebAPI service for this preexisting database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add [JsonProperty(PropertyName="can_personalize")] data annotation to the result set class, the data loads into the objects.